# C#.net embedded editable string

Tags: c#

I making an application launcher, Launcher.exe. I'm trying to have it load a config file from a URL. The URL value needs to be dynamic (so other people can use the app, loading a different URL) but also be able to have the same value on other computers (with out a config file, single exe) Is there ***any*** way I can edit an embedded resource. Even if I have a separate exe that just edits launcher.exe embedded resource. I'v been Googleing that for that last 2 hrs.

Or is there a way I can edit a value in the program itself, that would be the same from computer to computer.

```
//Something like this: 
//open app.exe on comp1 
//setting --> URL = "http://stackoverflow.com"  
//Change/Save it to "http://google.com"
//close app.exe put app.exe on a flash-drive 
//open app.exe on Comp2
//setting --> URL = "http://google.com"
```

or

```
//open app.exe
//setting --> URL = "http://stackoverflow.com"
//close app.exe 
//open settingchange.exe
//edits app.exe setting
//setting --> URL = "http://stackoverflow.com" 
//Change/Save it to "http://google.com"
//close settingchange.exe
//open app.exe
//setting --> URL = "http://google.com"
```

How can I do this with no config files.

Comment: Have you thought about alternative ways to do this? For example, a command-line option that lets you specify which URL to load?

Comment: I'm a little confused by "but also be able to have the same value on other computers". Do you mean that you want to have some default path hard-coded, but give people the ability to change it at run-time if they wish? I think a command-line switch is the best option, as @Jacob pointed out

Comment: Yes I want it to be editable, but I want the setting to be saved to the exe not to the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you could have a second exe that changes the first one. 
You could do that with [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil), but it will not be particularly easy (due to a chronic lack of examples and documentation).
Here's an [example on Justin Etheridge's blog](http://www.codethinked.com/static-method-interception-in-net-with-c-and-monocecil) that you may be able to tweak to change your URL on the fly directly in the compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the settings tab in Properties. It stored the information in the `AppData` on each unique computer.

Comment: This wouldn't give him the ability to copy the .exe alone to a jump drive and have the change persisted.

Comment: If he wants to do that, he has to make a writable directory on a server and even that won't be unique if he changes computers or ip address.

Comment: this isn't an asp app, its an executable